# Commend "setLayout(null)" and draw rectangle

Tags: java, swing, drawing

I'm have a question about why is the rectangle not drawing while I have set commend `frame.setLayout(null)`. But when I delete this line or change to `setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,1,1))` a rectangle is drawn but my buttons are in different places. Is there any other possibility of drawing?

```
public void Frame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Tamagotchi v0.1");
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.add(pandaLabel);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //frame.setLayout(null);
    StatusBar s = new StatusBar();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(43, 159, 119));
    contentPane.add(s);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.red);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(20, 20, 300, 300);
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) *"my buttons are in different places"* Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) The logic of this GUI starts to go wrong right around `frame.setSize(width, height);`. Since frames have different chrome (window borders) on different systems, this guess can only be correct on one (version of one OS). Instead, the preferred size ..

Comment: .. of the active area should be overridden (note that sometimes this will be the content pane, but will more often be the 'game play area' - which might be surrounded by other things like buttons and combo boxes etc.) then call `pack()` on the frame to fit it.

Comment: If not sure, it pays to check the meaning of words. For example, I speak only English, and knew that word made no sense here, yet I felt the need to check exactly what [the word 'commend'](https://www.google.com/search?q=commend+define) meant!

Comment: Take a look at Oracle's tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).